# how to run multiple instances of tile server on a single machine?

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, apache, tile-server

I installed OSM tile server on Ubuntu 14.04.
I followed instruction given here https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/ .
I want to perform "vertical load balancing" for case of tile server.

In case of Geoserver , it is done like this http://boundlessgeo.com/2013/04/geoserver-in-a-clustered-configuration-part-2/
These steps can't be followed in case of tilserver because tile server consists of many individual components like Mod_tile, renderd, mapnik, osm2pgsql and a postgresql. Mod_tile is an apache module

For running many instances of tile server,I am thinking of running multiple instances of Apache web-server(in which renderd and mod_tile are plugged on which tile request will be received)with HAProxy.
But I can't find exact solution.

Is there any other solution possible?

If running two instances Apache2 is only solution then how to do it?

(I have gone through some sites for many instances of apache2 but necessary httpd.conf of Apache2 is not available in Ubuntu ,so I cannot configured necessary module )

Comment: You should try virtualization technology. You can install VM-s, and use different ip address and use loadbalancer. when a machine is offline, it can be routed to b machine where all files, tiles are mirrored.